# locateAllOnScreen finds the same image more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

So I have this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHZVB.jpg) ,this [Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4AIo.jpg) image and this code:

**Image:**

[image]

**Template:**

[image]

**code:**

```
list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(r'C:\Desktop\chromatic.png', grayscale = True, confidence = 0.9))
```

The picture is in grayscale for faster times but even if I put the original it doesn't work.

So the problem is that it finds 6-7 occurrences instead of 4, so the template matches the same image more than once. I tried switching confidence etc but nothing works. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same problem. The problem is that locateAllOnScreen finds the same image several times shifted by 1-2 pixels. I solved the problem by filtering the found images (distance between images should be more than 10 px: (x1-x2)<sup>2</sup> + (y1-y2)<sup>2</sup> > distance<sup>2</sup>).

```
def locate_all(path, confidence=0.9, distance=10):
    distance = pow(distance, 2)
    elements = []
    for element in pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen(path, confidence=confidence):
        if all(map(lambda x: pow(element.left - x.left, 2) + pow(element.top - x.top, 2) > distance, elements)):
            elements.append(element)
    return elements
```